# Bad connection at friends home, good connection at my home

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-10

I bought a new laptop a few months ago and I have problems with staying connected to wifi. When at home I don't have any problems but when I am at a friend it keeps disconnecting when playing an online game (Guild Wars 2). It randomly throws me out of the game and have to reconnect. At that point, when looking at the different wifi signals my laptop picks up, it only shows the one I am currently connected to.

Also, at my friend's home, his laptop can detect more wifi signals compared to my laptop.

Can someone explain what might be wrong and how I can fix it?

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: You need to find out if he's using 5Ghz or not.

Comment: My network adapter is 802.11b and his is 802.11n, does that help?

Comment: Only ancient machines would be .11a/b only. Is the machine more than 4 years old or brand new? Go to device manager, network adapters to get its model number.

Comment: I bought mine around july this year. My adapter is Qualcomm Atheros ar946x.

Comment: Its modern, your should support .n and maybe AC (that x makes the model not specific). Go to your laptop manufactures website and get the lastest wifi driver for your model.